# Helping get more users 200+ reputation

Tags: discussion, best-practice, voting, reputation

As seen on Area51 and mentioned here in meta few times:
Site leaving Beta (we are close aren't we?) should have around 150 users with 200+ rep and currently there's only 90 of them.

**Is it a good idea to go thru the users who are right below
200 treshold, search for their Q&A and vote up the good ones?**

Apparently I don't wanna cheat the rep system, I just thought they probably have some pretty good Q&A that I would rate and fav anyway if I would stumbled upon them.

I just wanted to recheck with community if it's ok.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I've done this myself too. But don't limit yourself to those in the 170-200 range: sometimes newcomers can give good answers too and rise to 200 quickly. Like certain users that were at 126 when they asked certain questions on Meta, but saw an increase soon after.

Comment: Thanks @Jan! You made me laugh loud - and that's even better then rep push-up ;) I've just went through first few users and their posts and I've had a great educative time...

Comment: Can you also access [the review pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review)? They contain posts from first-time users, and either need a correction (answers that are not real answers), or an upvote!

Comment: @Jan Yes I can access them. I didn't know about this site feature before. It's not linked from anywhere? I will take a deeper look later. No more votes for today anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes

1. it's good to use all your votes if you can, but please only vote for things that are *worthy* of an upvote.
2. it's also good to focus on your new incoming users and give quality new users a boost to welcome them to your site, see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review

Related blog post:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Comment: Thanks for article @Jeff. Like I mentioned in my initial question - my intention is not to abuse rating system in any way therefore I do consider my votes seriously. Yesterday I spent all my votes, but I kinda spread them amongst more users so only one made it over 200 thanks to my votes. I also found out that to give out 30 responsible votes takes a lot of time and lot of reading (it was a good time and great reading though).

Comment: Also thanks to you & @Jan for pointing me to the /review section and encouraging me to support new users . I will try and help there a bit. Are there any guidelines or articles regarding moderating reviews that you would recommend?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is absolutely fine for questions/answers that you genuinely consider deserving a vote.